# Running Bat file on Win 7 machine

Tags: windows-7, parameters, batch-file, arguments

I have an executeable (Command line which requires arguments/parameters) i need to run on a Win 7 machine. I can run the executeable if i right click and choose run as administrator.  Of course, it returns an error code that the required command line parameters were not found.  In addition, the executable will create an error log if it has a problem, errors out, throws an exception, etc.  I then created a batch file and added MyProgram.exe param to it, and right clicked that and chose run as administrator.  I get nothing.....no return code, no error log.  I created a shortcut on the desktop to the batch file and changed its advanced properties to run as administrator and still nothing.  Anyone have any ideas?  I need to run this executable with params from a batch file on a Win 7 machine. Thanx

Edited:

I guess maybe it could be a problem with my Batch file, since i am a novice at those as well.  I simply had one line:

MyProgram.exe MyImportFile.txt 1 1

Comment: nothing really to post, its a call to the program and its parameter :   MyProgram.exe MyParameter

Comment: "C:\Program Files\test\Test.exe" "C:\Program files\test\docs\test.txt" 1 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a shortcut on Desktop to cmd.exe
There you have your commandline. Right click your new shortcut, run as administrator.
Then run your bat file or your exe directly with your parameters.

Comment: so i changed my desktop shortcut to :  cmd.exe "mybatchfile" and it still doesn't work

Comment: @tombom: I think it would be better then to have a shortcut for the target executable with arguments supplied as needed, with no batch file interference.

Comment: @Andriy.....got the same result, just pops up the command line window.....besides, this doesn't answer my question. SInce i need to run the executable from a batch file, i need to get away from Shortcuts

Comment: @Shane: Actually a more correct way to use cmd.exe explicitly to run the batch file (or any command for that matter) would probably be `cmd.exe /c "yourbatchfile"`.

Comment: my batch file looks like this:  "C:\Program Files\test\Test.exe" "C:\Program files\test\docs\test.txt" 1 1